# Run or coexist two react applications on same session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to run two completely independent react applications on the same domain and same port so that two apps co-exist on the same page. These two apps have different stores and there is no link between both of them. How to achieve this??

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking? You should be able to just render your apps into their own root elements using `ReactDOM.render`

Comment: @Matt thanks for the reply. How can I link both the applications before adding it to the render?

Comment: Your question says there is no link between the two applications, not sure what you mean by link

Comment: @Matt they both are not linked but I want to show them in the same page under same host.